# How to implement custom constraint using C++?

Tags: drake

I am trying to reimplement [littledog.ipynb](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/examples/littledog.ipynb) using C++. I find it is hard to translate the function `velocity_dynamics_constraint` and have 3 questions

1. What is the function of `ad_velocity_dynamics_context`? Can we ignore it?
2. How to reimplement `velocity_dynamics_constraint` using C++? Do I have to create a new class like `class VelocityDynamicsConstraint : public drake::solvers::Constraint`? Is three any easier way to implement it?
3. Why we need to consider `isinstance(vars[0], AutoDiffXd)` condition?

```py
# Some code from https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/examples/littledog.ipynb
ad_velocity_dynamics_context = [
    ad_plant.CreateDefaultContext() for i in range(N)
]

def velocity_dynamics_constraint(vars, context_index):
    h, q, v, qn = np.split(vars, [1, 1+nq, 1+nq+nv])
    if isinstance(vars[0], AutoDiffXd):
        if not autoDiffArrayEqual(
                q,
                ad_plant.GetPositions(
                    ad_velocity_dynamics_context[context_index])):
            ad_plant.SetPositions(
                ad_velocity_dynamics_context[context_index], q)
        v_from_qdot = ad_plant.MapQDotToVelocity(
            ad_velocity_dynamics_context[context_index], (qn - q) / h)
    else:
        if not np.array_equal(q, plant.GetPositions(
                context[context_index])):
            plant.SetPositions(context[context_index], q)
        v_from_qdot = plant.MapQDotToVelocity(context[context_index],
                                              (qn - q) / h)
    return v - v_from_qdot
for n in range(N-1):
    prog.AddConstraint(partial(velocity_dynamics_constraint,
                                context_index=n),
                        lb=[0] * nv,
                        ub=[0] * nv,
                        vars=np.concatenate(
                            ([h[n]], q[:, n], v[:, n], q[:, n + 1]))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the function of ad_velocity_dynamics_context? Can we ignore it?

The context caches the intermediate computation result for a given `q, v, u`. It is very common that several constraints are imposed on the same set of `q, v, u` (for example, consider at the final time, we typically have a kinematic constraint on the final state, say the robot foot has to land on the ground and its center of mass is at a certain location. At the same time we we have the velocity dynamics constraint on the final state). Hence these different constraints can share some intermediate computation result, such as the rigid transform between each adjacent links. Hence we cache the result in `ad_velocity_dynamics_context`, and this `ad_velocity_dynamics_context` can be used later when we impose other constraints.

> How to reimplement velocity_dynamics_constraint using C++? Do I have to create a new class like class VelocityDynamicsConstraint : public drake::solvers::Constraint? Is there any easier way to implement it?

That is right, you will need to create a new class VelocityDynamicsConstraint. The main challenge in implementing this class is to write the three overloaded `DoEval` function for three scalar types (double, AutoDiffXd, symbolic::Expression). You can refer to [PositionConstraint](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/inverse_kinematics/position_constraint.cc) as a reference. And for the moment you can ignore the case to call `DoEval(const Eigen::Ref<const AutoDiffXd>&, AutoDiffXd*)` with a `MultibodyPlant<double>` case, and only implement the this DoEval function with `MultibodyPlant<AutoDiffXd>`.

> Why we need to consider isinstance(vars[0], AutoDiffXd) condition?

Because when the scalar type is AutoDiffXd, we want to compare not only the value of q against the one stored in context, but also its gradient. If they are different, then we need to call SetPositions to recompute the cache. When the scalar type is double, we then only need to compare the value.

Comment: Does `DoEval(const Eigen::Ref<const AutoDiffXd>&, AutoDiffXd*)` do the same thing like `if isinstance(vars[0], AutoDiffXd)` do?

Comment: I find snopt solver ([snopt_solver.cc](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/6482339ea56389d5adc2c27249b9857db9fa17b7/solvers/snopt_solver.cc#L346)) always call `DoEval(const Eigen::Ref<const AutoDiffXd>&, AutoDiffXd*)`. So I may can not ignore the case to call `DoEval(const Eigen::Ref<const AutoDiffXd>&, AutoDiffXd*)`

Comment: @matheecs Sorry for the belated reply. Right you will need to implement the DoEval function for the AutoDiffXd case. One example in Drake QuaternionIntegrationConstraint https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/optimization/quaternion_integration_constraint.h, see how it implement DoEval through a templated DoEvalGeneric function